# concatenation of strings in oracle apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have problem to display picture in PL/SQL Dynamic view Content (Apex Oracle).

Below is problematic row of code:

```
sys.htp.p( '<img src="'https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/cgdev/test/cool/'||'kk1.ID'||'.1.png'"/>');
```

where is `kk1.ID` is `ID` relevant to report.

I need to get result:

```
"https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/cgdev/test/cool/2.1.png"
```

How can I concatenate strings in the right way?

Regards,
Stefan

Comment: `sys.htp.p( '<img src="https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/cgdev/test/cool/'||'kk1.ID'||'.1.png'"/>');` 
Or better - use [APEX_STRING.FORMAT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.2/aeapi/FORMAT-Function.html#GUID-77E01643-C482-476C-9404-F3AEDDACCD22)

Answer (score 0):

Line #5 shows how it should look like. Your *problem* was in wrong enclosing `kk1.id` into single quotes, I think. I left opening and closing `IMG` tags out. Add them, if necessary.

```
SQL> with kk1 (id) as
  2    (select 2 from dual)
  3  select
  4    '"https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/cgdev/test/cool/' || kk1.ID ||'.1.png"' col
  5  from kk1;

COL
----------------------------------------------------------
"https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/cgdev/test/cool/2.1.png"

SQL>
```